# javascript ask by attempting to do

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this cause an 'Aw, Snap!' Error (like a plugin failed, showing a file with a face that has its eyes crossed out)?

```
var vid;
var youtube;
var youtube1='<object style="margin:5px;height:175px; width:235px"><param name="movie" value="';
var youtube2='"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="';
var youtube3='" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" height="175" width="235"></object>';



if(vid=vid.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','')){
    vid=vid.slice(0,11);
    vid='http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vid+'?version=3&feature=player_detailpage&autohide=1';
}else{}
youtube=youtube1+vid+youtube2+vid+youtube3;
$('#TV').html(youtube);
```

it used to work when my code was like so:

```
if(youtube.search('http://www.youtube.com/v/')== -1){
    vid=vid.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','');
    vid='http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vid+'?version=3&feature=player_detailpage&autohide=1';
    }else{}
```

I would have thought that asking if js can do something whilt attempting it would work and be faster!? I'm sure I've seen this done in php.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: best else statement ever.

Comment: You will [not see any performance improvement](http://jsperf.com/inline-if-is-pointless) by performing the `replace` inside the conditional check. I would move it to maximize readability.

Comment: did you snip code from the middle? you declare "vid" but never initialize it, and then begin performing string methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this statement is ALWAYS(*) true, either if the replacement is done or not:

```
vid=vid.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','')
```

So you don't need an if for that. This other statement MAY be true:

```
youtube.search('http://www.youtube.com/v/')== -1
```

depending on the value of the variable youtube.

(*) except if the replace() gives you an empty string as @Chris Shouts pointed.

Comment: The statement `vid=vid.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','')` would evaluate to false if `vid` is an empty string after the replacement. It will **not** always evaluate to true.

Answer (score -1):

This line looks a little odd:

```
if(vid=vid.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','')){
```

Are you meaning to *assign* the value from `vid.replace` to `vid` or just check the value?  The `if` condition doesn't seem to produce a clear `Boolean` value.

So, in this case, trying to get the `if` condition to both perform the action *and* return a `Boolean` probably won't work for you because the new code in the condition doesn't return a `Boolean` based on the execution of the action.  (Technically, the condition *does* return a `Boolean`, but it's not based on the success/failure of the `replace` action.)

Comment: What?
What do you mean Boolean?

Comment: @Nicosunshine - The condition in the `if` statement must resolve to either `true` or `false`.  This "true/false" value is known as a `Boolean` type.  Since this is just a comment, I'll link to the [Wikipedia Boolean data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) page.

Comment: it means that your new if statement is ALWAYS true. And if that is correct, you don't need an IF at all.

Comment: @TLS heh I know what a Boolean is, I meant that in javascript even if there is a false and a true values, everything else evaluates to a truthy or falsy, so I was trying to understand what you meant.

Comment: @Nicosunshine - In that case, the new condition (the assignment) always resolves to `true` (like Guumaster mentioned), so even if the `replace` doesn't actually replace anything, the code inside the `if` block will execute.

Comment: should this be a try statement instead? (I am both asking if 'replace is posible while attempting it)

Comment: @BenMuircroft - The `try` statement probably won't help here because the `replace` method doesn't throw an exception when no replacement occurs.  It looks like the original code (with the `search` in the `if` condition) is the right way to go.

Comment: I think you won't see any performance improvement in changing two string functions (search/replace) for one. Javascript is really really fast with that. Look into other places of your code to improve.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this has been downvoted. Did I miss something or not answer the question?